# Create hybrid mobile apps using Phonegap and without installing SDKs for platforms to be supported

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have downloaded phonegap-2.9.0 from http://phonegap.com/. It contains doc folder and lib folder containing sample projects (I think so) in the folders named after the platforms. After going through the net articles it seems like I have to install SDKs of all the platforms I wish to support for an app. I don't want to do so.

Is there any way I can use a single editor and create apps that will support other platforms, and how would I use the JS files in lib folder ?

I want to use JavaScript, CSS and HTML.

Comment: You have to include the jar files of the platform that you intend to support.

Comment: Ok, but what editor should I use..

Comment: I know this is an old question. This tutorial could help people http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2015/8/how_to_create_an_awesome_hybrid_mobile_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, for Android you need to use Eclipse IDE, Install Android SDK in your local system, Install ADT plugin for eclipse, then you can create new Android project from File > New

For more information

http://phonegap.com/developer/

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

For iphone development you need a MAC Machine, XCode IDE

For windows phone, need to install windows phone SDK, IDE -> Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone

Visit http://docs.phonegap.com/en for more info

Comment: Thanks @sajay, I would like to share what I have understood so far, please correct me if I am wrong.  It means a developer can use a platform according to his comfort level or familiarity and create the app using phone gap libraries, that's it. Now that app will be usable in other platforms. There is no need to repeat same procedure with other SDK's.                                                              I have some experience with C# using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. What would be better for me then ?

Comment: We use phonegap to build hybrid app with web technologies like html5,css3, javascript etc. The benefit of phonegap is that it will help you to access device hardware like accelerometer, camera etc. To develop app with phonegap you dont need much proficiency in  any high level languages like c#, objective c or java.

Comment: ok @sajay but what editor you would like to suggest me to start with and what you have to say about my understanding of the concept so far :) ?

Comment: It totally depends on the platform and audiences you are targeting. Also you need to have the IDE for development. Visual studio comes with a price, while Eclipse is free and also which device you have for testing etc

Comment: I have to create an app for all major mobile paltforms :(

Comment: Okay then you need to setup different development IDE, would you mind sharing what kind of app you are developing?

Comment: it will be a sample app for a presentation, but I also have to show some data access functionality. I also have to give its demo in devices like android phone, windows phone and IPhone.

Comment: If you don't intend to use device hardware you can think of responsive webdesign, or you can develop using mobile frameworks like jquery mobile or sencha touch. In this case you only have one codebase, but you have to access it using a browser

Comment: thanks that info was very helpful, if I need to access device hardware as well then what can be done. you mentioned responsive webdesign in that case how data is accessed irrespective of platform currently in use.

Comment: see, if you are pulling data with a http request it doesnt matter which platform you are using. In case you need to access device hardware you need to stick with a native app (using phonegap or a specific programming language). Please give a uparrow to my answer if you find its useful, thanks

Comment: hope I could do that, but it requires reputation points anyways this discussion brings me very close to the required answer :).. In case I used phonegap and a specific programming language will the final product run in other devices.

Comment: Ajendra, with phonegap you need to have multiple dev environment targetting each platform. (windows -> Visual Studio for windows phone and windows phone sdk, iphone (Mac OS nd XCode), android (Eclipse and Android SDK etc). If you are targetting multiple platforms you need to do a bit more work. you can add me in skype sajay.cv

Answer (score 2):

There actually is a way to develop for PhoneGap without having to install all the various SDK's contrary to the accepted answer.

All you have to do is create a single codebase and push it to GitHub.  An example Hellow World app can be found [at this repository](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world).  Then, you can go to [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), and PhoneGap Build will compile the code for all the different devices.  As for developing the app, all you have to do is edit the files in the `www/` folder and add whatever pages you wish.  Be sure to check out the Docs on that PhoneGap Build link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> http://app.phonegap.com/

This is the solution your looking for.

To set up check this. http://devgirl.org/2014/04/22/introducing-the-phonegap-developer-app/

You don't want to use any SDK or IDE. text editor and Device (Android, iOS) will do the wonder. Currently it supports Android and iOS only.